# Use of global power label in a KiCad schematic

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, kicad

I am using a DC-DC buck converter to convert 12V DC to 3.6 V DC. The screw terminals J1 are the battery inputs.  The other side is the output.

How do I facilitate the power supply to other components in my schematic (which is not present at the moment?)

Is using global power label recommended? If so how do I make use of it?

My schematic is large and may go upto 3 pages long.

[image]

Comment: *Is using global power label recommended?* Yes, and you already used them "GND" and "VCC". Multi-sheet schematics *must* be heirarchical. Read about it here: https://docs.kicad.org/6.0/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#hierarchical-schematics There are many other resources available.